# Screensaver app on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, screensaver, background-service

I would like to create an app which would pop-up fullscreen when user is not interacting with the device; the first tap would then close it. So it's exactly like a screensaver. It should "run" 24/7. Display should always be lit. Battery is of no concern.

I've already done this on android, but my WP skills are lacking and complete research would take me at least a couple of days, so I'm asking any WP gurus out there:

can the same functionality (screensaver) be achieved on the Windows Phone 8.1 platform?
If so, which are the basics that should be covered (programming-wise)?

**Edit**:
The only solution I have at this moment is changing the LockScreen background on a 30minute interval.
I'm still not sure whate happens in 2 weeks as some info suggests that the registered task will expire. Not to mention that LockScreen is shown only a few seconds.

**Edit 2**:
Subquestion: is there a way to keep LockScreen shown at all times (while charging)? Or maybe lauch lock screen from code?

Comment: Can't find a good link for you, though you might take a look at Windows Phone 8.0 For Absolute Beginners (search Channel 9), as the instructor builds a screen saver in that tutorial.  But yes, it can be done - you'll want to leverage background task (which runs, I believe, every 30 minutes, though you can set it to a lower interval for testing), and the app will need permission to interact with the lock screen.

Comment: There is also a Windows Phone 8.1 tutorial, but I recommend doing the 8.0 one first as some fundamentals applicable to WP in general are covered in detail in the 8.0 series.

Comment: OK, so it can be done and I do appriciate the screensaver video tip, but the WP8.0 30(+-10min) PeriodicTasks are not good enough. I  want to know if WP8.1 and its BackgroundAgent is the solution I'm looking for. It must work 24/7, cca 1min of user timeout,... without limitations. If not, It's no good for me.

Comment: I found something on the developer.nokia.com wiki: "Dynamic lock screen for Windows Phone 8". It seems like this could work: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8 
edit: it uses PeriodicTask therefore the limit is still 30mins to change the background image.

Comment: I believe 30 minutes is the limit and it can't be changed - it's to conserve battery use.

Comment: What you are trying to do goes against all the bases of Windows Phone so if you can come up with a way of making it work in future there will be an update that will brake it. Microsoft invested lots in preventing just such thing.

Comment: It's for a store, not for a normal user. Eg. When customers walk by or check the phone they can see the latest prices and the "screensaver" always pops up after the user idle timeout.

Comment: @TineUršič I have the same requirement , Did you implement it?

Comment: @Eldho I'm sorry to say that the project was scrapped. At least for the time being. Too many problems and no (real) solution.
... All this is from a year ago, maybe now there are more options ...
Good luck.

Comment: @TineUršič Thanks , If i had a solution, i will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone doesn't usually allow apps to pop up on their own. Exceptions are made for specific [usecases such as voip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206983(v=vs.105).aspx). There is also no way for [an app that isn't running in the foreground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx) to realise that the user hasn't interacted with the screen for any number of minutes.

Therefore your only option is to use the [inbuilt lockscreen functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj571206(v=vs.105).aspx).